# htaccess rewrite rule: show page without showing filename in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a php script which can show some image based on a **QUERY_STRING**

example:

> example.com/img.php?**IMAGE_1**

but i want same result to be shown even if user visit

> example.com/IMAGE_1

i tried this code from a forum but it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On  # enables url rewriting

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ img.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule matches 1+ of any word character or hyphen in an URI that must not match an existing file or directory. If match is successful it converts path to query string with `img.php`.

Comment: example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: There is no error in the rule I provided. Make sure you test with **just this code** in your .htaccess, nothing else